# Firefox Addon Builder preferences-services not working for me--Why?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to make a button in the Firefox Add-on Builder that will change the URL that the searchbar uses. To change the URL, I have a panel that shows when the button is clicked, and in the panel is a series of buttons.

In a second `.js` file (not the `main.js`) I have the functions that are supposed to change the `keyword.url` function using the `preferences-service` module.

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
function changekeywordurl(url) {
    alert('Search Engine Changed');
    require("preferences-service").set('keyword.url', url);
}
```

and the HTML for the panel is:

```
<button onclick="changekeywordurl('http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=')">Yahoo</button>
```

Sorry if I am making a really dumb mistake; this is my first attempt and an add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML pages loaded by your extension don't have any special privileges - they are just like regular web pages. In particular, the function `require()` isn't defined in this context. What you need to do is to load a content script into the panel because a content script can communicate back to the extension. This content script could look like this:

```js
// Add event listener in the content script, the page cannot "see" content script
// functions
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("searchButton");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", changekeywordurl, false);

// Send a message to the extension if a button is clicked
function changekeywordurl(event)
{
  var button = event.target;
  self.postMessage(button.getAttribute("_keywordURL"));
}
```

And the button in the page would look like this:

```html
<button _keywordURL="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p="></button>
```

Then your extension can listen to messages from the content script and use the necessary SDK modules.

Comment: I am confused as to where this goes and how to implement it. Where do I put this script (in which file), and what do I do with the other script that I mentioned in the question?

Also, I don't see the `preferences-service` module in there, so how is it supposed to change the `keyword.url` preference? Thanks for helping.

Comment: This code is in the content script attached to the page, typically via page-mod. Please see the docs for a more thorough explanation of content scripts: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't help. Do I put the script above in the main.js file, or do I embed it in the HTML file? And where do I put the function to change the `keyword.url`? This is extremely confusing to me.

Comment: Neither - the script above is a content script, it should be a separate file in the `data/` directory and you should specify it in the `contentScriptFile` parameter when you create the panel. As to manipulating `keyword.url` - you should do that in `main.js` when you receive a message from the content script. See documentation on communicating with content scripts, link in the comment above.

Comment: OK, so I have a button in the HTML file, and I copied/pasted the content script into a `content.js` file. I then added `contentScriptFile: data.url("clicklistenize.js")` to the panel properties. The only question I have is, in here: `panel.port.on("WHAT GOES HERE?", function() {`. It would be simple, but since the message is an attribute that could change, I am not sure what to put there. Thanks

Comment: @Ian: If the content script uses `self.postMessage()` then you shouldn't use `worker.port` to receive the message - rather specify `onMessage: function(data) {...}` when constructing the panel ([documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html)). `worker.port` is used when you need various message types but then the content script would have to use `self.port.emit()` to send the message ([documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html)).

Comment: I think I am going to move this to a new question. Thanks for the help!